# Custom class for UITableViewController Datasource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I have an extensive hierarchy of UITableViewControllers that I need to navigate through. Each one is going to need it's own Custom View Controller. My data-source for any particular tableview is currently an array of strings, like "A,B,C,D,E,F". My didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is a long list of if statements, like this (pseudocode):

```
if cell.text = "A"
    alloc init AViewController
    navigationController push aViewController
if cell.text = "B"
    alloc init BViewController
    navigationController push bViewController
```

I think this is messy. There has got to be a cleaner way to do this. Any "best practices" for this? My best idea is to make a custom class that contains a cellTitle and a viewController Class. Then I can use an array of those as my datasource, and do this kind of thing:

```
UITableViewController *newView = [custom.viewControllerClass alloc] init...
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property on your top-level table view controller:

```
@property (strong) NSDictionary *viewControllerClassForCell;
```

In `viewDidLoad` or other initialization method:

```
viewControllerClassForCell = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [AViewController class], @"A",
    [BViewController class], @"B",
    // etc.
    nil];
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
Class vcClass = [self.viewControllerClassForCell objectForKey:cell.text];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[vcClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSClassFromString()** and build the string with your cell.text.

Something like this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSString * className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ViewController", cell.text];
UIViewController * vc = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc]
```

Or, In a more classic way, you can have a method which accepts the name as the parameter and return a instance of the selected viewController

```
- (UIViewController*) viewControllerForName: (NSString*) theName {
  if ([theName isEqualToString:@"A"]) return [[AViewController alloc] init];
  else if (....)
}
```

and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[self viewControllerForName:cell.text]]
```